# Помогите с MySql в NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Привет, я хочу чтобы записывались данные в таблицу, они записываются, но если я пробую записать ещё раз, то он создает дубликат. Собственно вопрос:
Мне нужно просто вывести в отдельную переменную чтобы не создавались они?
Вот мой код:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "steam_bot"
});

function RecordUsers() {
  console.log("Соединение установлено!");
  var sql = "UPDATE `users` SET name ='Test'  WHERE steamid = '"+steamID+"'";
  con.query(sql, function (err, rows, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record update");
    if (rows[0] < 1) {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(name, steamid) VALUES ('Testovino','"+steamID+"')";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            console.log("1 record insert");
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Гуглил, везде Пыха..

Comment: не знаком с технологиями, но что вы ожидаете в `row[0]` при выполнении `update` запроса? он набор данных то не возвращает. Может, конечно,  количество затронутых строк, но что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Можно в самой структуре таблицы сделать поле 'steamid' уникальным, тогда записи одинаковые не будут вставляться. Ну и я тоже не пойму, зачем там UPDATE/. Может, вместо него SELECT, чтобы проверить, есть ли записи с таким steamID

Comment: т.е. Я могу сделать запрос SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = '"+steamID+"'? Но он все ровно возвращает пустые строки, но как мне сделать обробтчик от них?. @МаксимСтепанов

Comment: Я честно говоря, тоже не знаком с технологиями, но по идее можно так:  получить в переменную значение  запроса 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE steamid = '"+steamID+"' ' , это число совпадений, если оно больше 0, не добавлять

Comment: в mysql есть конструкция как `insert ... on duplicate key update .. `

Comment: @teran А есть примеры как это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674458/223826 ответ в комментарии

Comment: @teran Он дублирует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, я изменил запрос на SELECT

```
var sql = "SELECT `steamid` FROM `users` WHERE steamid = '"+steamID+"'"
```

Потом спарсил ответ через result. И проверил на наличие строк:

```
if (result < 1) {
var sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(name, steamid) VALUES ('Testovino','"+steamID+"')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        console.log("1 record insert");
    });
}
```

Потом добавил else:

```
else {
        var sql = "UPDATE users SET name='Snegan' WHERE steamid='"+steamID+"'";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            console.log("1 record update");
        });     
    }
```

И проверка на дубликаты выполнена! Спасибо что не прошли мимо